# jQuery: if key "someKey" pressed

Tags: jquery, keyup

i know that i can detect a key, which has been pressed with the following code:

```
$('input').keyup(function (e){
if(e.keyCode == 13){
    alert('enter');
  }
})
```

But i need to know if any key was pressed.
pseudocode:

```
if ($('input').keyup() == true)
  { 
      doNothing();
  }
  else {
      doSomething();
  }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `keyup` is fired when a key is released use `keydown` to fire an event when a key is pressed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because 'keyup' will be fired when ANY key is pressed, you just leave out the `if`...

```
$('input').keyup(function (e){
  // do something
})
```

Merging this into your current code, you could do something like...

```
$('input').keyup(function (e){
  alert('a key was press');

  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      alert('and that key just so happened to be enter');
   }
})
```

Comment: but i need the "else" part, if a key is not pressed.
I have to handle not only the "you pressed a key" part, but also the "you pressed no key" part.

Comment: How on earth should you determine that the user didn't press a key? The absence of the .keyup() event firing means that the user currently isn't releasing a key.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input').keyup(function (e){
    alert("You pressed the \"Any\"-key.");
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if the user didn't press a key you could use a setInterval() function.

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    //Do this if no key was pressed.
}, 2000);
```

Note that you should clear the interval as well `clearInterval()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input").keypress(function() {
  alert("hello.");
});
```